# How to setstate array with dynamic keys in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have the following state value as an array. How can I push a new list `var newList` into `Students` array where the key `Students` is dynamically generated and sometimes it might be pushing to `Teachers` array.

The current list is available at

```
let key = "Students"
console.log(this.state.school[key])
```

My state is following and I need to push the new array of students or teachers based on the `key`.

```
this.state = {
    school: {
        Teachers: [
            {
                id: "1",
                name: "T1",
            },
            {
                id: "2",
                name: "T2",
            }
        ],
        Students: [
            {
                id: "1",
                name: "S1",
            },
            {
                id: "2",
                name: "S2",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the state in immutable way,

```
let oldArray = this.state.school[key];
this.setState({
    school: {
        [key]: [
          ...oldArray,
          ...newList
        ]
    }
})
```

By this way, you can push your `newList` to either *Students* or *Teachers* based on **key** value.

Comment: @HareeshSNair, Can you tell me in which line you get syntax error

Comment: I have updated the answer, can you please check whether it is working

Answer (score 0):

State is immutable. You can use immutability-helper for ease of manipulation. But in plain JavaScript, the code is as follows:

```
let { school } = this.state;
school = Object.assign({}, school);
school.students = school.students.concat(newStudents);
this.setState({ school });
```

With [immutability helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper/), the code will be a bit less.

```
let { school } = this.state;
school = update(school, {
  students: {
    $push: newStudents
  }
);
this.setState({ school });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out immutability helper. https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper/

```
import update from ‘immutability-helper’;
...
const newState = update( this.state, {
    school: {
        [key]: { $push: newList }
    } }
```

Comment: You gotta import update from immutability helper lib. Check out the docs I have sent

Comment: @HareeshSNair I have updated my answer to include an import statement.